# Redirection based on location but without affecting search bots

Tags: plugins, redirect, geo-data

A client has a successful UK site based powered by Wordpress and is launching a US arm. While the US sub-sites are built, he has a holding page that is visible to US visitors, who are redirected to it from the usual home page by the [Geo Redirect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geographical-redirect/) plugin.

I've just realised that Geo Redirect is also redirecting Google's (and other search engines') bots, which is not at all good; does anyone have a relatively easy solution that would do what Geo Redirect does so well but would not affect visits by search engine bots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search**

Help Google to determine the site language and to serve the right page for the users in different countries. Mark up language attributes correctly. Use `<html lang="en_UK">` and `<html lang="en_US">`. Use `<link rel="alternate" hreflang="x" />` in page `<head>`. It's also important to specify site targeting in Google Webmaster Tools.

**Referrers**

I believe people residing in UK will link to your UK-targeted site, not US-targeted. And inversely.

**User Experience**

It's always a good practice to leave the user the ability to choose preferred site himself.

**Advice**

Don't use any redirection plugins. Google advise sounds the same:

> Avoid automatic redirection based on the user’s perceived language
>   ([Multi-regional and multilingual
>   sites](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&hlrm=en&answer=182192#1)).